# What does msDS stand for and why do so many things start with it?

Tags: active-directory

While working with Active Directory, I have run across a number of items of the form `msDS-something`
For Example:

```
msDS-PasswordSettings
ms-DS-MachineAccountQuota
msDS-LockoutThreshold
msDS-LockoutObservationWindow
```

Why do these all start with msDS? What does it stand for? Is there a reason for this or is it simply a result of a legacy naming convention?

Comment: Microsoft Directory Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for Microsoft Directory Services and indicates Microsoft-specific attributes.